# iOS XCUITest - Simulate hardware keyboard tab key

Tags: ios, xcuitest

Is there a way to simulate pressing the tab key on a hardware keyboard in XCUITest for iOS? There is `XCUIElement.typeKey()` but it's only available on macOS. I also tried `typetext("\t")` but that didn't have the same effect as pressing the tab key.

Comment: Have you tried `typetext("\n")` ? It's kind of simulate trying to type the "Next" keyboard button.
You can also try something like `XCUIApplication().keyboards.buttons["return"].tap()` according to the Action button on the keyboard.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. Return and tab work differently, and tab is what I need to test. `XCUIApplication().keyboards` only gives access to the on-screen keyboard, and the tab key is usually only on the hardware keyboard.

Comment: What do you exactly want to test with the tab key ?

Comment: The tab key advances focus through the active text fields. I want to check that it does so in the expected order and skips fields that are supposed to be disabled.